# Error on Google Colab saying Requires CUDA, which is not available on your system

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, colmap

I am trying to run the following code on Google colab from this library:
https://github.com/colmap/pycolmap
I use Google Colab because it offers preinstalled CUDA

```
output_path: pathlib.Path
image_dir: pathlib.Path

output_path.mkdir()
mvs_path = output_path / "mvs"
database_path = output_path / "database.db"

pycolmap.extract_features(database_path, image_dir)
pycolmap.match_exhaustive(database_path)
maps = pycolmap.incremental_mapping(database_path, image_dir, output_path)
maps[0].write(output_path)
# dense reconstruction
pycolmap.undistort_images(mvs_path, output_path, image_dir)
pycolmap.patch_match_stereo(mvs_path)  # requires compilation with CUDA
pycolmap.stereo_fusion(mvs_path / "dense.ply", mvs_path)
```

However, I am getting error saying :
Dense stereo reconstruction requires CUDA, which is not available on your system.

```
  ----> 2 pycolmap.patch_match_stereo(mvs_path)  # requires compilation with CUDA
          3 pycolmap.stereo_fusion(mvs_path / "dense.ply", mvs_path)
    
    RuntimeError: [mvs.cc:38] ERROR: Dense stereo reconstruction requires CUDA, which is not available on your system.
```

Can someone explain why? Thank you.

When I check for CUDA, it says available

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
```

I have also selected GPU using the following
Go to Menu > Runtime > Change runtime.

Comment: https://github.com/colmap/pycolmap/blob/743a4ac305183f96d2a4cfce7c7f6418b31b8598/pipeline/mvs.cc#L37 -- that exception looks like it is raised if you trying using features which require a GPU on a build without GPU support. This isn't a colab or CUDA problem. You have installed a non GPU build of that code my reading of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://colmap.github.io/install.html):

> Note that the COLMAP packages in the default repositories for Linux/Unix/BSD do not come with CUDA support, which requires manual compilation but is relatively easy on these platforms.

There's the steps to install it from source with CUDA enabled.

```
!git clone https://github.com/colmap/colmap.git
!cd colmap
!git checkout dev
!mkdir build
!cd build
!cmake ..
```